# vimrc not being respected in terminal vim

Tags: vim, macvim

some settings in the vimrc file i use are not being respected in terminal vim but when i use the gui mvim it works perfectly fine. I was wondering what I am doing wrong. I am also running iterm2 and using the same theme as being used in vim (Gotham). You can see the differences in the pictures I attach below.

Notice specifically the difference in colors, the gui version uses the correct colors.
terminal vim(incorrect version):
[image]

GUI version(correct colors):

[image]

here is the .vimrc I'm using

```
    let g:startify_custom_header =
      \ map(split(system('fortune | cowsay'), '\n'), '"   ". v:val') + ['','']
let g:startify_custom_footer = [
        \ '',
        \ ]

let &t_Co=256
let base16colorspace=256
syntax enable

if strftime("%H") < 16
  set background=light
  colorscheme solarized
else
  set background=dark
  colorscheme gotham256
endif


set ttyfast
set magic
set showmatch
set clipboard=unnamed
set autoread
set encoding=utf8
set paste
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set number
set numberwidth=6
set guifont=Sauce_Code_Pro_Plus_Nerd_File_Types:h15
set guioptions-=L
set guioptions-=r

set invlist
set listchars=tab:▸\ ,eol:¬,trail:⋅,extends:❯,precedes:❮
highlight SpecialKey ctermbg=none " make the highlighting of tabs less annoying
set showbreak=↪

set wrap "turn on line wrapping
set wrapmargin=8 " wrap lines when coming within n characters from side
set linebreak " set soft wrapping
set showbreak=… " show ellipsis at breaking

set autoindent " automatically set indent of new line
set smartindent

let g:NERDTreeQuitOnOpen=1
" remove some files by extension
let NERDTreeIgnore = ['\.js.map$']
" Toggle NERDTree
nmap <silent> <leader>k :NERDTreeToggle<cr>
" expand to the path of the file in the current buffer
nmap <silent> <leader>y :NERDTreeFind<cr>

set ts=2 sw=2 et
let g:indent_guides_start_level = 1
let g:indent_guides_auto_colors = 1

if !exists('g:airline_symbols')
    let g:airline_symbols = {}
endif

let g:WebDevIconsUnicodeDecorateFolderNodes = 1
let g:webdevicons_enable_airline_statusline = 0

let g:airline_left_sep = ''
let g:airline_left_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_symbols.branch = ''
let g:airline_symbols.readonly = ''
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = ''

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
highlight SyntasticErrorSign ctermfg=red ctermbg=237
highlight SyntasticWarningSign ctermfg=yellow ctermbg=237
highlight SyntasticStyleErrorSign ctermfg=red ctermbg=237
highlight SyntasticStyleWarningSign ctermfg=yellow ctermbg=237



call plug#begin()
Plug 'tpope/vim-sensible'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plug 'bling/vim-airline'
Plug 'nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides'
Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plug 'mhinz/vim-startify'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
Plug 'chriskempson/base16-vim'
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Plug 'whatyouhide/vim-gotham'
Plug 'benmills/vimux'
Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
call plug#end()
```

Comment: It looks fine to me. The colors won't match exactly since terminal vim only supports upto 256 colors, while macvim has 65k colors. Your color scheme has chosen an approximation for the 256 colors. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @FDinoff thanks for clarifying I did not know about the 65k colors on macvim

Comment: Actually... its closer to 16 million. I multiplied in my head wrong. (its rgb with 255 colors each)